# vb.net Excel : Issue with getting Chart CategoryNames

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-addins

I need, for some reason, the category names of my chart. Here's what I got so far:

```
xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
Dim wsnat As Excel.Chart = TryCast(xlWorkbook.ActiveChart, Excel.Chart)
If Not wsnat Is Nothing Then    
    Dim axxxis As Excel.Axis = DirectCast(wsnat.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary), Excel.Axis)
    Dim areyoukiddingme As Object = axxxis.CategoryNames
    Dim arr As Array = DirectCast(areyoukiddingme, Array)
    For q As Integer = 0 To arr.GetUpperBound(0)
        Debug.Print(arr(q).ToString) ' HERE, the array 'arr' has two things which are EMPTY!
    Next
End If
```

My problem is, that the array (arry) has the correct amount of EMPTY objects. If I do the whole thing in VBA, it works as expected. But it does not for VB.net. Any clues? 
Here's the code in VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Set chrt = ActiveChart
    Dim names As Variant
    names = chrt.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryNames
End Sub
```

This sub nicely outputs the category names of my chart!

Comment: When I run the .Net code. the For-Loop fails for index 0; the array has a lower bound of one(1).  Also, `arr(q)` is a late-bound call.  Use `arr.GetValue(q)` to retrieve the indexed item.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with "late bound"! That OPTION STRICT must have gotten disabled again! I'll give it a try when I am back.

Comment: The `arr.GetValue(q)` didn't solve the problem, the late-bound call was it.
I switched Option Strict to ON (180 `ctype`s later) it has worked!